# How would a mathematician solve the following physics problem without using the infinitesimal approach?

Tags: calculus, physics

I was solving a physics problem and I wondered how could it be done using a more formal approach and without resorting to the mindset of infinitesimals

When it comes to calculating the centre of mass of a continuous object, let's say a cylinder of radius $ r $ and length $ L $ with variable density $ \rho(x) $ at each point of the cylinder. (and taking $ x = 0 $ as the left side of the cylinder). I go through the following thought process.

Starting from the formula for the center of mass of a continuous body of mass:

$$
x_{cm} = \frac{\int x \, dm}{\int \, dm}
$$

I think of dividing the cylinder into very small layers, and one layer has mass $ dm = \rho(x) dV(x) $

In this case, the volume of that small layer of the cylinder is $ dV = \pi r^2 dx  $ where $ dx $ is the very small width of the layer. So $ dm = \rho(x) \pi r^2 dx $

I replace $ dm $ in the original formula:

$$
x_{cm} = \frac{\int_0^L x \rho(x) \pi r^2\, dx}{\int_0^L \, \rho(x) \pi r^2 dx} \\
x_{cm} = \frac{\int_0^L x \rho(x) \, dx}{\int_0^L \, \rho(x) dx}
$$

And I keep going about solving the problem doing the integration.

In all this case, I have used Calculus but I have gone against something that I have read from many Calculus books, saying that $ dx $ in the integral is a meaningless operator to determine the variable of integration. However, in this case, thinking of $ dx $ as a very small width helps a lot solving the problem.

I'm aware of the historical context of Calculus and also how engineering and physics majors use this constantly but from a mathematical point of view is not formal.

I'm curious about how a mathematician would solve this problem if he doesn't want to use the "physicist" approach of treating $ dx $ as an infinitesimal and something "active" in the calculations?

Comment: Replace your $dx$ by $\Delta x_i$ and form a Riemann sum and take limit of Riemann sum to get the Riemann integral. That's how I do mentally when I see all this technique in physics books.

Comment: Consider one very thin strip of width $\delta x$ and take the limit as $\delta x\to0$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. If that's not helpful, please tell meand I'll elaborate.